# Get extra data null at "onNewIntent" for singletask activity

Tags: android

I have to activity `HomeActivity` which have the launchModel of `singleTask`,and another `BActivity`.

The process maybe:

```
HomeActivity --> BActivity -->HomeActivity
```

When come to `HomeActivity` from `BActivity` I will put some extra data like this:

Inside `BActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onGoto(UpdateElement element) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("x", element.longitude);
    intent.putExtra("y", element.latitude);
    intent.putExtra("z", element.level);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And I try to process the data like this:

Inside `HomeActivity`:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    if (intent != null) {
        float xx = intent.getFloatExtra("x", 1000);
        System.out.println("txx:getFloatExtra:" + xx);

        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            float x = intent.getExtras().getFloat("x", 2000);
            System.out.println("txx:getExtras.getFloat:" + x);
        }
    }
}
```

I can get the output "new intent called" throught the logcat, however I always get null for the x,y,and z.

log:

```
6129-6129/com.I/System.out﹕ txx:getFloatExtra:1000.0
6129-6129/com.I/System.out﹕ txx:getExtras.getFloat:2000.0
```

What's going on?

Comment: Try to use `intent.getFloatExtra("x", 0);` instead of `intent.getExtras().getFloat("x", 0)`

Comment: @PG_Android: Does not work.

Comment: Are you getting null means values printed as a "0" for X and Y?Also try with remove this line if (intent.getExtras() != null) {

Comment: Have you checked value for element.longitude and element.latitude??

Comment: Yes,I have checked using the debugger, and I am sure the data is put inside the extra of the intent.

Comment: Debugger screenshot:http://imgbin.org/images/19458.png

Comment: Ok. So just remove this line (intent.getExtras() != null) {  from your code only and it will work fine for you.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not exactly sure how does this line result in the unexpected result? line `float xx = intent.getFloatExtra("x", 1000);` ran before the `intent.getExtras() != null`, but it still return the `1000`.

Comment: It will return obvious 1000 because by default you are getting value as a 1000

Comment: Default value would be used if and only if the transferred value is null, and the value I sent is "17", so it return "1000" means it does not get my value.

Comment: Has this ever been resolved? I've been through 15 different StackOverflow posts and still haven't found a solution.